# return binding.rename(pathModule._makeLong(oldPath), Error: EPERM, operation not permitted

Tags: node.js, file-rename, fs, file-move

I have the following script:

```
var fs = require("fs");
fs.renameSync(__dirname + "\\file.txt", __dirname + "\\destination");
```

Simply trying to move the file *file.txt* into the folder *destination* with Node.js using the File System API.

Here is exactly what I run an as elevated Command Prompt as Administrator in Command Prompt and Windows PowerShell, the results plus the details:

```
Microsoft Windows [Version 6.3.9600]
(c) 2013 Microsoft Corporation. All rights reserved.

C:\WINDOWS\system32>cd..

C:\Windows>cd..

C:\>cd Users

C:\Users>cd Leo

C:\Users\Leo>cd Desktop

C:\Users\Leo\Desktop>cd directory

C:\Users\Leo\Desktop\directory>takeown /F "C:\Users\Leo\Desktop\directory"

SUCCESS: The file (or folder): "C:\Users\Leo\Desktop\directory" now owned by user "PC\
Leo".

C:\Users\Leo\Desktop\directory>npm cache clean

C:\Users\Leo\Desktop\directory>node script.js
fs.js:636
  return binding.rename(pathModule._makeLong(oldPath),
                 ^
Error: EPERM, operation not permitted 'C:\Users\Leo\Desktop\directory\destination'
    at Error (native)
    at Object.fs.renameSync (fs.js:636:18)
    at Object.<anonymous> (C:\Users\Leo\Desktop\directory\script.js:2:4)
    at Module._compile (module.js:460:26)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:478:10)
    at Module.load (module.js:355:32)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:310:12)
    at Function.Module.runMain (module.js:501:10)
    at startup (node.js:129:16)
    at node.js:814:3

C:\Users\Leo\Desktop\directory>node -v
v0.12.4

C:\Users\Leo\Desktop\directory>npm -v
2.13.1

C:\Users\Leo\Desktop\directory>npm list
C:\Users\Leo\Desktop\directory
└── fs@0.0.2
```

I have Full Control Access (Ownership) of the related folders, subfolders and files:

```
 C:\Users\Leo\Desktop\directory

 C:\Users\Leo\Desktop\directory\script.js

 C:\Users\Leo\Desktop\directory\file.txt

 C:\Users\Leo\Desktop\directory\destination

 C:\Users\Leo\Desktop\directory\node_modules\fs\index.js

 C:\Users\Leo\Desktop\directory\node_modules\fs\package.json
```

Ran *takeown /F* of each of these successfully just in case.

Also tried alternative syntax on the file and folder paths:

```
fs.renameSync("C:\\Users\\Leo\\Desktop\\directory\\file.txt",
 "C:\\Users\\Leo\\Desktop\\directory\\destination");
```

Spyware protection and Virus protection disabled.

Updated and running the latest versions of *node*, *npm* and *fs*.

PC is Windows 8.1 Pro x64 with latest updates.

No Outbound Firewall rules blocking *node* or *npm*.

I have Inbound Firewall rules allowing:

```
C:\Program Files\nodejs\node.exe
C:\Program Files\nodejs\npm
```

Feeling like I've exhausted all options, any ideas would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: I don't know about Windows, but on Unix both "oldPath" and "newPath" need to be of the same type (either filename or directory name, but you can't mix them). So try `"\\destination\\file.txt"`

Comment: It worked! Thank you for the quick reply @robertklep

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can only rename file to file or directory to directory, but you can't mix them, such as in your situation (file to directory).

In that case, add the name of the file to the `newPath` argument:

```
fs.renameSync(__dirname + "\\file.txt", __dirname + "\\destination\\file.txt");
```